# Django template tags filter by slug

Tags: python, django

I have a many-to-one relationship between organizations and events. One organization can have many events. I have a template for showing all events that everybody can see filtered by city. But I want the organization detail view to show events belonging only to a specific organization.

models.py

```
class Organization(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield(max_length=27)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
  [...]

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Events(models.Model):
  org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
  time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(
    max_length=25,
    choices = CITY_CHOICES,
    default = 'NY'
    )
  [...]
  def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.org, self.time)
```

I use this template tag to filter events by city (NY for this one):

```
@register.inclusion_tag('mysite/event_list.html')
def event_ny_tag(event):
    return {'events': Events.objects.filter(linn='NY')}
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
  url(r'^organizations/$', OrganizationList.as_view(), name='organizations'),
  url(r'^events/$', EventList.as_view(), name='events'),
  url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', OrgDetailView.as_view(), name='org_detail'),
]
```

But how can I filter events only by one specific organization? There are only two cities but 20 organizations. How to do it without hardcoding it? With a slug?

This is not a copy paste. Just a sample code similar to mine.

Comment: I think what you want is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Answer (score 1):

Since the events have the foreignkey Organization. You can get the list of events associated with an organization in its detail view template like this:

```
  {% for event in organization.events_set.all %}
        {{ event }}
  {% endfor %}
```

**Update:** To filter according to a semester you could make use of a custom template filter that passes the semester as argument along with the event list, like this:

```
  @register.filter
  def semester(events, sem):
      return events.filter(semester=sem)
```

and do this in the template

```
  <!--Semester 1-->
  {% for event in organization.events_set.all|semester:"sem1" %}
       {{ event }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works. Thank you!
But to take it a step further. How can I now filter them by semester? The model has a semester choice field.